# How to reproduce this letter in LaTeX

Tags: fonts

[image]

I wanted to enter this character in my LaTeX code.But I am not able to find the command for it. Can anybody help me with it?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}$ (with `amsmath` package).

Comment: can we use \mathbb{c} (small letter 'c') instead of capital letter 'C'. I am not getting the output if I am using small c

Comment: Yes, as in my answer for this version of your question.

Comment: you should have a look to [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14)

Answer (score 3):

This is the answer for the clarified question (lowercase c):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathbbol}
\begin{document}

\[
\mathbb{c}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\ensuremath{\mathds{C}}%dsfont

\textcolonmonetary%textcomp
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But OP wants (lowercase) c.